# Find DOM parent container of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, javascript-objects

Is it possible to traverse up the DOM when looking for the parent container of an image that has been added to a JavaScript object?  I have the below object and array of object code:

```
var builtVehicle = {pattern: "../images/fire1192015.png", 
vehicle: "../images/van1192015.png", 
wheel: "../images/wheels3.png"};

var createdVehicles = [
{pattern:"../images/checkerboard1192015.png",       
vehicle:"../images/car1192015.png", wheel:"../images/wheels1.png"}, 
{pattern:"../images/fire1192015.png", vehicle:"../images/truck1192015.png",     
wheel:"../images/wheels4.png"},]
```

I am looping through both elements looking for an exact image source match for both the vehicle, wheel and pattern properties.  If the builtVehicle object is unique (meaning different vehicle, wheel pattern image source properties than the objects in the createdVehicles array), push it to the array.  However, once the loop through the createdVehicles object finds a match, I'd like to be able to reference the div parent containers that contain the images defined in the objects.  Below is the function I'm currently working with:

```
builtVehicle = {
            vehicle: jaVehicle,
            wheel: jaWheel,
            pattern: jaPattern,
            }

    var matchVehicle = function (vehicle, stack) {
        for (var i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
         if ((vehicle.pattern === stack[i].pattern) && (vehicle.vehicle === stack[i].vehicle) && (vehicle.wheel === stack[i].wheel)) {

//find DOM div parent that the image resides in so something like 
//stack[i].closest('div'), even though that won't work    
//Add some DOM manipulations             

         return;
          }
      }
      // Push the vehicle to array if it didn't complete match
      stack.push(vehicle);
    };
    matchVehicle(builtVehicle, createdVehicles);
    });
```

My HTML will look like this, so I'd want to be able to reference the div.name3 and possibly the div#product3 containers:

```
<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product3">
  <div class="fltLeft positionRelative name3">
   <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment uniqueWheel3" src="../images/wheels1.png">
   <img class="pattern patternInShipment uniquePattern3" src="../images/fire1192015.png">
   <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment uniqueVehicle3" src="../images/car1192015.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I've done some online searching but couldn't find an answer if what I'm trying to do is possible or if I should be trying a different approach.  I've tried stack[i].closest('div') and stack[i].parent() but obviously that's not working.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `vehicle` an array of jquery objects?

Comment: No, vehicle is a property found in the object (builtVehicle ) and the array of objects (createdVehicles) i'm comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var filtered = $.map(createdVehicles, function(v, k) {
  return $.map(builtVehicle, function(value, key) {
    return v[key] === builtVehicle[key] ? value.split("/").slice(-1) : null
  })
}); 

var res = $("img").filter(function(i, el) {
  return filtered[0] === el.src.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
});

console.log(res.parents());
```

```js
var builtVehicle = {pattern: "../images/fire1192015.png", 
vehicle: "../images/van1192015.png", 
wheel: "../images/wheels3.png"};

var createdVehicles = [
{pattern:"../images/checkerboard1192015.png",       
vehicle:"../images/car1192015.png", wheel:"../images/wheels1.png"}, 
{pattern:"../images/fire1192015.png", vehicle:"../images/truck1192015.png",     
wheel:"../images/wheels4.png"}];

var filtered = $.map(createdVehicles, function(v, k) {
  return $.map(builtVehicle, function(value, key) {
    return v[key] === builtVehicle[key] ? value.split("/").slice(-1) : null
  })
}); 


var res = $("img").filter(function(i, el) {
  return filtered[0] === el.src.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
})

console.log(res.parents());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product3">
  <div class="fltLeft positionRelative name3">
   <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment uniqueWheel3" src="../images/wheels1.png">
   <img class="pattern patternInShipment uniquePattern3" src="../images/fire1192015.png">
   <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment uniqueVehicle3" src="../images/car1192015.png">
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```